# What is default Oracle 11g maxConnections setting?

Tags: oracle11g

I would like to set in my c3p0 pooling the right maxConnection value, but I don't know the setting in Oracle. 
I have no rights to ask Oracle directly.

I suppose Oracle has been installed without special configuration, so I think it there should be deafult value, but google search somehow does not show any clear answer.

Onyone have idea?
I think Oracle is on Linux installed.

Comment: Maximum connections supported by the listener, maximum sessions supported by the database instance, or something else? The maximum pool size should be determined by the application's needs and expected load, surely, and the listener/database configured to support that - not the other way around? There isn't necessarily a clear link - other applications may need connections separate from your pool, for example.

Comment: Maximum connections supported by the listener. I know I will have big load, so I would like to use the maximal possible. Thats clear, that I cannot directly copy that value into my apps config (my case: I will but there half of it), but I need to know, what the max is...

Comment: Unless you are configuring a `CONNECTION_RATE` your listener will be limited by the amount of sessions your DB is tuned to have.

Comment: OK, so what is the default amount of sessions? :)